# Normalizing the frequency of letters in a given .txt file

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, normalization, word-frequency

The problem: Given a txt file, find the normalized frequencies of all the letters in the document.

For example if given letters.txt containing "aaabb"

Output would be:

Letter | Frequency

a         0.6

b         0.4

Non-letters or numbers should be ignored.

My solution so far:

Since they want to input a text file, my main() should receive command line arguments.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
```

I've made an EOF check using getchar()

```
    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF){
```

and an if statement that checks if the char that getchar() is within the ASCII values for a->z or A->Z

```
  if (argv[1][c] >= 'a' && argv[1][c] <= 'z' || argv[1][c] >= 'A' && argv[1]<= 'Z')
```

2 things here - I dont know if argv[1][c] is the right way to go about writing this but intuitively it made sense to me.

Once the check is satisfied, I want the corresponding letter to update a count specifically for its # position in the alphabet. Therefore needing a  declared array that iterates for that letter each time it is found.

```
count[26];
```

Here is where I'm having troubles associating the letter a or A to position count[0] in the count array. I don't know how to code this part.

Comment: Unrelated, but important: "Since they want to input a text file..." - You're *sure* the argument isn't a file *name*, and *that* is what you're tasked with calculating frequencies over ? I suspect you're either (a) supposed to process input from `stdin` in the absence of a filename given as an argument, or (b) if a filename is given, process input from *that*.

Comment: To begin with, learning about [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) and [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) is a good start. Then considering that you most likely is using the ASCII alphabet, [an ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) is also good to have. From there you should easily be able to get from a sequence of letters to a histogram of these letters, and then can easily calculate their relative occurrences.

Comment: Sorry If I'm following you correctly, you're asking me whether I'm supposed to calculate the frequencies from stdin or from just the name of the txt file?

Comment: When you say *"Non-letters or numbers should be ignored"* does that mean they don't figure in the total count? So in `"a1234567879"` the `'a'` frequency would be normalised to `1.0`? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried. Much better than a few code snippets.

Comment: Yes weather that is what I meant, and okay will do!

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an `int` array that is of size 52 and have the first half of the array be for lower-case character counts and the upper half be for uppercase?

So in pseudocode:

```
#define ALPHA_COUNTS (52)
#define UPPER_OFFSET (26)

int counts[ALPHA_COUNTS] = {0};

for (char c : the_file_stream) {
    if (c is an alphabet character) {
        if (c is a lowercase character){
            ++counts[c - 'a'];
        } else {
            ++counts[c - 'A' + UPPER_OFFSET];
        }
    }
}
```

Even easier would be to just create a table for all ASCII characters and just populate it for alphabet characters:

```
#define ASCII_COUNT (127)

int counts[ASCII_COUNT] = {0};

for (char c : the_file_stream) {
    if (c is an alphabet character) {
        ++counts[c];
    }
}
```

Then later on, you could just iterate through the set of [Aa-Zz] and check the counts of each of the characters.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the statistics gathering by counting the occurrence of *all* input.
Non-letters or numbers should be ignored **in the result**.

```
unsigned long long count[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {0};
int ch;
while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF){
  count[ch]++;
}
```

Now only sum the ones that are letters

```
unsigned long long sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<=UCHAR_MAX; i++) {
  if (isalpha(i)) {
    sum += count[i];
    // fold into lower case
    if (isupper(i)) {
      count[tolower(i)] += count[i];
      count[i] = 0; 
    }
  }
}
```

Print their frequency

```
for (int i=0; i<=UCHAR_MAX; i++) {
  if (isalpha(i) && count[i] > 0) {
    printf("%c %f\n", i, 1.0*count[i]/sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just for clarity, count[tolower(i)] converts the uppercase letter to lower case then adds 1 to the count of that letter.  Why do we need to add count[i]=0 then?

Comment: @Code_Penguin To prevent printing in the next loop.  `count[i]=0` is not needed if later code uses `if (islower(i) && count[ch] > 0) { printf ...`.  Variations could be applied.  The important issue is that the file could be MBytes long and best to simplify the statistics gathering and do a little more work in the statistics analysis.

Comment: So cool :) I tried to implement it all - http://pastebin.com/HLb3Lsfk  I fed it a txt file it output all all letters in the text but all their frequencies are set to 1, and it doesnt just display lower case letters but upper case ones as well. 

Why is it only displaying one for frequency?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways to approach the problem. You can make use the the functions provided in `ctype.h` (e.g. `isalpha`, `tolower`, `toupper`, etc.), or for the limited number of tests required, you can simply test the characters directly using arithmetic or basic bitwise operations. For example, you can test if a value is between `'a'` and `'z'` for lower-case, and for all characters the `6th-bit` in `7-bit ASCII` is the *case-bit*, so simply toggling the case-bit will change a character from upper-to-lower or vice versa.

The *read* then *analyze* approach *chux* outlined is an excellent approach to take. Any time you can separate input/output from processing data, you provide yourself a great deal of flexibility.

Using that logic, an example of using arithmetic and simple bitwise operations to analyze the frequency of *alpha*-characters (`[A-Za-z]`) which occur in a file can be written similar to the following. *Note*, the program will read from the filename provided as the first argument (or from `stdin` by default if no filename is given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    unsigned long long count[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {0}, sum = 0;
    int c, i;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) count[c]++; /* fill count */

    for (i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++) {/* freq of only chars  */
        if ('A' <= i && i <= 'Z') {   /* fold upper-case     */
            count[i ^ (1u << 5)] += count [i]; /* into lower */
            count[i] = 0;                   /* zero index    */
        }
        if ('a' <= i && i <= 'z')           /* if lower-case */
            sum += count[i];                /* add to sum    */
    }

    printf ("\n total characters [A-Za-z]: %llu\n\n", sum);
    for (i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++)
        if (count[i] > 0 && ('a' <= i && i <= 'z'))
            printf (" %c%c : %.2f\n", i ^ (1u << 5), i, 1.0 * count[i]/sum);
    putchar ('\n');

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);      /* close if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Examples Use/Output**

Using your example of `'aaabb'` the program produces the following:

```
$ ./bin/char_freq < <(echo "aaabb")

 total characters [A-Za-z]: 5

 Aa : 0.60
 Bb : 0.40
```

A slightly longer example shows the full character selection of only `[A-Za-z]`:

```
$ ./bin/char_freq < <(echo "*(a)123A_a/B+4b.")

 total characters [A-Za-z]: 5

 Aa : 0.60
 Bb : 0.40
```

Look over this answer as well as all the others and let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Chuckling... It was a great suggestion for the arrays declared `UCHAR_MAX + 1` `:)`